# SQL Server query Insert into select and new data

Tags: c#, sql-server, insert-into

I need some correction with my query in C# & SQL Server.

I have a table called `LoggedIn` with name, password and clockin columns. I want it to insert into the table where name and password is from another table AND the clockin is the current time now.

```
string belepve = "INSERT INTO LoggedIn VALUES (SELECT name, password FROM Login WHERE password =" + Kod.login1 +" ,@MyDate";

SqlCommand command4 = new SqlCommand(belepve, con);

command4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyDate", DateTime.Now);
```

And then I just Execute the query.

Comment: what is `, @date` end of your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple  issues here.

First is the second parameter should also go as `SqlParameter`.

Second you have missing parenthesis at end.

Third you would need to specify the column names in which values should go in `LoggedIn` table.

Your working code would  be something like:

```
string belepve = @"INSERT INTO LoggedIn (name,password,LoginDate) 
                          VALUES (SELECT name,password,@MyDate 
                                  FROM Login 
                                  WHERE password =@Password
                                  )";

SqlCommand command4 = new SqlCommand(belepve, con);

 command4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyDate", DateTime.Now);
 command4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Kod.login1);
```

Assuming that you have columns in `LoggedIn` table as named `name`,`password` and `LoginDate`, you might need to adjust the column names which you have actually in  your table.

If you have same number of columns which  you are already selecting then you can do it more simple like following:

```
SELECT name,password,@MyDate 
INTO LoggedIn
FROM Login 
WHERE password =@Password
```

But you need to be careful in the order of  columns selecting otherwise value might go in different column than in  what is expected.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I read somewhere that I don’t have to specify the columns if I fill all the columns of the table. Isn’t that true?!

Comment: yes, if we have columns in `select` then you can but it's a good practice to speicfy as otherwise `name` value might get inserted in `password` column if order is not specified carefully.

Comment: @MártonGergő i have also added anoother way which is more  cleaner if  you specify order of columns correctly then that might also work.